# What is * .* in for loop in Bash?

Tags: bash

```
cd /var/spool/myname
for i in * .*;
do
    ...
done
```

What is `* .*`? As I understand, `for i in * .*` = `for i in /var/spool/myname`.

Comment: `*` is the glob for all non-hidden files (not starting with a period), and `.*` is the glob for files starting with a period

Comment: If you enable the `dotglob` option, `for i in *; do` would suffice.

Comment: BTW, `for i in /var/spool/myname` will run the loop just once, with `i` set to "/var/spool/myname". If you want a list of files in that directory, you need to use something like a wildcard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` is all the files in the directory except those starting with `.`.  The `.*` is all the files that start with `.`.

Basically it's trying to get every file in the directory. One potential problem is that `.*` will also return `.` which is the current directory and `..` which is the parent directory.